# How do I detect a collision between two rectangles

Tags: c++, collision-detection, sdl-2

I have a player with destination

```
srcRect.w = 100;
srcRect.h = 64;
destReact.x = 1535 / 2;
destReact.y = 400;  
destReact.w = srcRect.w * 2;
destReact.h = srcRect.h * 2;
```

and a rock of dest and src

```
srcRect1.w = 64;
srcRect1.h = 64;
srcRect1.x = 0;
srcRect1.y = 0;

destReact1.x = 250;
destReact1.y = ypos;
destReact1.w = srcRect1.w * 2;
destReact1.h = srcRect1.h * 2;
```

I want to detect when they collide

Comment: What have you tried so far? What research have you done?

Comment: hey, providing the dimensions are not at all helpful, unclear what you want to do and why? please explain what you are thinking of doing, and where you are stuck.

there are no details of what rock is, why and how they are supposed to collide, what srcRect/1 and destReact/1 mean.

Comment: This is very basic geometry that you were taught in school and thought you never would find any use for.

Comment: They collide if they overlap

Comment: Think in one dimension first. A collision in 1D might be conceptually simpler. Then it should be easy to increase the number of dimensions, just treat x and y separately... it's a collision in 2D when you have a collision in 1D for both x and y.

Comment: Answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58073251/collision-detection-rectangle-rectangle-algorithm)

Answer (score 4):

The player and the rock, both have a bounding rect. There is a collision, if the rectangles intersect.

Since you're using SDL2, have a look at the function [SDL_IntersectRect](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_IntersectRect):

```
SDL_bool SDL_IntersectRect(const SDL_Rect * A,
                           const SDL_Rect * B,
                           SDL_Rect * result);
```

> Calculate the intersection of two rectangles.
>
> **Return Value**
>
> Returns SDL_TRUE if there is an intersection, SDL_FALSE otherwise.